# How can I add a base table to an existing entity creating TPH model using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an existing table in my database called CarDesign that has a one to one relationship with Project. I want to add a base table called Design to use in a TPH table. So then I can add discriminators for things like BoatDesign. The problem is entity framework wants to just drop the old table and make a new one. How can I keep my data and have a discriminator to represent the current records?

I'm using entity framework 5 with SQL. I am also going to update to entity framework 6 if that helps the issue. Project is asp.net MVC4 with c#

```
Mapping

public class CarDesignMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<CarDesign>
    {
        public CarDesignMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

            // Properties
            //this.Property(t => t.Name)
            //.IsRequired();

            this.Property(t => t.RowVersion)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(8)
                .IsRowVersion();



            // Relationships
            this.HasMany(t => t.InputVoltages)
                .WithMany(t => t.CarDesign)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("InputVoltageCarDesign");
                    m.MapLeftKey("CarDesign_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("InputVoltage_Id");
                });

            this.HasMany(t => t.LensColors)
                .WithMany(t => t.CarDesign)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("LensCarDesign");
                    m.MapLeftKey("CarDesign_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("LensColor_Id");
                });

            this.HasMany(t => t.LightSourceColors)
                .WithMany(t => t.CarDesign)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("LightSourceColorCarDesign");
                    m.MapLeftKey("CarDesign_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("LightSourceColor_Id");
                });

            this.HasMany(t => t.Standards)
                .WithMany(t => t.CarDesign)
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("StandardCarDesign");
                    m.MapLeftKey("CarDesign_Id");
                    m.MapRightKey("Standard_Id");
                });

            this.HasOptional(t => t.LightSource)
                .WithMany(t => t.CarDesign)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.LightSourceId);
        }
    }
```

model

```
public class CarDesign
{
    public CarDesign()
    {
        Approvals = new List<Approval>();
        Standards = new List<Standard>();
        Connectors = new List<Connector>();
        InputVoltages = new List<InputVoltage>();
        LensColors = new List<LensColor>();
        LightSourceColors = new List<LightSourceColor>();
    }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public PdsStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Guid SubmittedById { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Submitted By")]
    public virtual User SubmittedBy { get; set; }

    public Guid? ApprovedById { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Approved By")]
    public virtual User ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Approval Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? ApprovalDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Submit Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime SubmittalDate { get; set; }
    public string SubmittalDateDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return (SubmittalDate == null) ? "Not Set" : ((DateTime)SubmittalDate).ToString("MM/dd/yy");
        }
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Market and Uses")]
    public string MarketAndUses{get;set;}

    [Display(Name = "Target M & L")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double? TargetPrice { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Annual Qty")]
    public int? AnnualQuantities { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Current Draw")]
    public double? CurrentDraw { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Light Source")]
    public int? LightSourceId { get; set; }
    public virtual LightSource LightSource { get; set; }



    public LengthUnitOfMeasure LengthUnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public WeightUnitOfMeasure WeightUnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public PhotometricIntensityUnitOfMeasure LightIntensityUnitOfMeasure{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Connector> Connectors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InputVoltage> InputVoltages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LensColor> LensColors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LightSourceColor> LightSourceColors { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

so I would desire to have

public class CarDesign : Design

{

}

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to adopt TPH inheritance, EF will have to create a table for the base class `Design`, thus droping your old CarDesign table. You can try to use migrations to avoid losing data but I've never tried to implement TPH with existing data so I cannot garantee that migrations will work for it (I'm afraid it probably won't).

As for the discriminator, EF already handles this for you.

The classes would look like this:

```
public abstract class Design
{
    Public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class CarDesign : Design
{
    ...
}

public class BoatDesign : Design
{
    ...
}
```

And then, you can choose to create a single DbSet for Design or you can create one DbSet for each subtype. Your choice here:

```
public DbSet<Design> Designs { get; set; }
```

or:

```
public DbSet<CarDesign> CarDesigns { get; set; }
public DbSet<BoatDesign> BoatDesigns { get; set; }
```

Or you can have all three DbSets.

In case you want query Designs DbSet and have it return only CarDesigns, you can do it like this:

```
var finishedCarDesigns = context.Designs.OfType<CarDesign>().Where(cd => cd.Finished = true);
```

Also, you may find this link useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you started with `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BarID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then added a base class `Baz`

```
public class Foo : Baz
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BarID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Baz
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ApprovedBy { get; set; 
}
```

You could add your sql to the migration like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Foos", "BarID", "dbo.Bars");
    DropIndex("dbo.Foos", new[] { "BarID" });
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Bazs",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                ApprovedBy = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(),
                BarID = c.Int(),
                Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Bars", t => t.BarID)
        .Index(t => t.BarID);

    //Put your sql here to run before the table is dropped
    Sql(@"INSERT INTO dbo.Bazs (Name, BarID, Discriminator) 
          SELECT Name, BarID, 'Foo' FROM dbo.Foos");

    DropTable("dbo.Foos");
}
```

The sql gets more complicated if you have foreign keys to fix up. The only other thing I can think of is to go in stages:

1. Make `BoatDesign` inherit from `CarDesign` and Migrate (a discriminator column will be added to the existing table)
2. Add a new class `CarDesign2` that also inherits from `CarDesign` (no database change required)
3. Move the properties applicable only to `CarDesign` into `CarDesign2` (no database change required)
4. Script a table name change in the database for CarDesigns to Designs (Sql Server will generate a script that will move the data as well as drop and re-create)
5. In the code change `CarDesign` to `Design` and `CarDesign2` to `CarDesign`
6. Look at the migration created by step 5. If it is dropping and recreating the `CarDesign` table then replace it with the sql generated in step 4, If it isn't woo-hoo!
7. Let us know how you get on